# Ensure generated links in TYPO3 use the absolute path

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-7.6.x, absolute-path

I have a website in TYPO3, it has a header and footer and a load of generated page links.

Is there any parameters or TypoScript that can be used that would enable all links to have absolute paths? e.g. the item that generates the menu might look like

```
<f:cObject includeAbsolutePath="true" typoscriptObjectPath="lib.content_subMenu" />
```

I basically need all page links to be absolute.

I am using Typo3 V7.6

Comment: You should update your TYPO3 installation. Your version is not supported anymore.

Comment: great advice @HeinzSchilling tell me something I don't know, but when your client wont update their server there is no choice. So its not really a very helpful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.absRefPrefix` might be your solution. But this could lead to drawbacks as well, e.g. in multi-domain environments. But in that case, you might work with conditions to set a proper domain name.

See details in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#absrefprefix).